# How to loop through a table and look for adjacent rows with identical values in one field and update another column conditionally in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have a table that has a field called ‘group_quartile’ which uses the sql ntile() function to calculate which quartile does each customer lie in on the basis of their activity scores. However using this ntile(0 function i find there are some customers which have same activity scores but are in different quartiles. I need to modify the ‘group-quartile’ column to make all customers with the same activity scores lie in the same group_quartile.

A view of the table values :

```
Customer_id  Product Activity_Score Group_Quartile
 CH002          T         2328                 1
 CR001          T         268                  1
 CN001          T         178                  1
 MS006          T         45                   2
 ST001          T         21                   2
 CH001          T         0                    2
 CX001          T         0                    3
 KH001          T         0                    3
 MH002          T         0                    4
 SJ003          T         0                    4
 CN001          S         439                  1
 AC002          S         177                  1
 SC001          S         91                   2
 PV001          S         69                   3
 TS001          S         0                    4
```

I used CTE expression  but it didnot work.
 My query only updates(from the above example) :

```
 CX001          T         0                    3
```

modified to

```
 CX001          T         0                    2
```

So only the first repeating activity score is checked and that row’s group_quartile is updated to 2.
 I need to update all the below rows as well.

```
 CX001          T         0                    3
 KH001          T         0                    3
 MH002          T         0                    4
 SJ003          T         0                    4
```

I cannot use DENSE_RANK() instead of quartile to segregate the records as arranging the customers per product in  approximately 4 quartiels is a business requirement.
From my understanding  I need to loop through the table -

1. Find a row which has same activity score and the same product as its predecessor but has a different group_quartile
2. Update the selected row's group_quartile to its predecessor's quartile value
3. Then againg loop through the **updated** table to look for any row with the above condition , and update that row similarly.
4. The loop continues until all rows with same activity scores (for the same product) are put in the same group_quartile.

--

THIS IS THE TABLE STRUCTURE I AM WORKING ON:

CREATE TABLE #custs

(

customer_id NVARCHAR(50),

PRODUCT NVARCHAR(50),

ACTIVITYSCORE INT,

GROUP_QUARTILE INT,

RANKED int,

rownum int

)

INSERT INTO #custs
   
 -- adding a column to give row numbers(unique id) for each row
    
SELECT customer_id, PRODUCT, ACTIVITYSCORE,GROUP_QUARTILE,RANKED,
    
Row_Number() OVER(partition by product ORDER BY activityscore desc) N
    
FROM
    
-- rows derived form a parent table based on 'segmentation' column value
    
(SELECT customer_id, PRODUCT, ACTIVITYSCORE,
    
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT ORDER BY ACTIVITYSCORE DESC) AS RANKED,
    
NTILE(4) OVER(PARTITION BY PRODUCT ORDER BY ACTIVITYSCORE DESC) AS GROUP_QUARTILE
    
FROM #parent_score_table WHERE (SEGMENTATION = 'Large') 
    
) as temp
    
ORDER BY PRODUCT

---

The method I used to achieve this partially is as follows :

-- The query find the rows which have activity score same as its previous row but has a 
different GRoup_Quartiel value.

-- I need to use a query to update this row.

-- Next, find any rows in this newly updated table that has activity score same as its 
previous row but a differnet group_quartile vale.

-- Continue to update the tabel in the above manner until  all rows with same activity scores 
have been updated to have the same quartile value 


 
I managed to find only the rows which have activity score same as its previous row but has a different Group_Quartill value but cannot loop thorugh to find new rows that may match this updated row.

select t1.customer_id,t1.ACTIVITYSCORE,t1.PRODUCT, t1.RANKED, t1.GROUP_QUARTILE, 
t2.GROUP_QUARTILE as modified_quartile 

from #custs t1, #custs t2 

where (

t1.rownum = t2.rownum + 1 

and t1.ACTIVITYSCORE = t2.ACTIVITYSCORE 

and t1.PRODUCT = t2.PRODUCT 

and not(t1.GROUP_QUARTILE = t2.GROUP_QUARTILE))

Can anyone help with what should be the t-sql statement for the above?
 Cheers!

Comment: What RDBMS is this?  SQL Server?

Comment: Also please post some actual code from your failed attempt.

Comment: I have inserted the code in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already worked out a basis `Group_Quartile` as indicated above, you can update the table with a query similar to the following:

```
update a
set Group_Quartile = coalesce(topq.Group_Quartile, a.Group_Quartile)
from activityScores a
  outer apply
  (
    select top 1 Group_Quartile
    from activityScores topq
    where a.Product = topq.Product
      and a.Activity_Score = topq.Activity_Score
    order by Group_Quartile
  ) topq
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35d32/3).

**Edit after comment:**

I think you did a lot of the work already by getting the `Group_Quartile` working.

For each row in the table, the statement above will join another row to it using the `outer apply` statement. Only one row will be joined back to the original table due to the `top 1` clause.

So each for each row, we are returning one more row. The extra row will be matched on `Product` and `Activity_Score`, and will be the row with the lowest `Group_Quartile` (`order by Group_Quartile`). Finally, we update the original row with this lowest `Group_Quartile` value so each row with the same `Product` and `Activity_Score` will now have the same, lowest possible `Group_Quartile`.

So *SJ003*, *MH002*, etc will all be matched to *CH001* and be updated with the `Group_Quartile` value of *CH001*, i.e. *2*.

It's hard to explain code! Another thing that might help is looking at the join without the update statement:

```
select a.*
  , TopCustomer_id = topq.Customer_Id
  , NewGroup_Quartile = topq.Group_Quartile
from activityScores a
  outer apply
  (
    select top 1 *
    from activityScores topq
    where a.Product = topq.Product
      and a.Activity_Score = topq.Activity_Score
    order by Group_Quartile
  ) topq
```

[SQL Fiddle without update](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35d32/6).

Comment: Hi Ian, Great solution. It works. Could you please explain how it works ?

Comment: I've added some more details; hope they help! Turns out trying to explain the code was more difficult than writing it. Let me know if I can clarify anything here.

Comment: Hey Ian, your explanation was helpful but honestly speaking I spent sometime reading the code before you sent the explanation and understood the logic. You were right, explaining code is difficult :)